# Medir distancia pero en tiempo api geolocation

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocalización, geolocation-api

Me interesa medir la distancia pero en minutos ya que este código me aloja distancia pero en km ¿cómo puedo obtener una distancia pero en minutos?

```javascript
rad = function(x) {return x*Math.PI/180;}
     
var R = 6378.137;
var dLat = rad( lat2 - lat1 );     
var dLong = rad( lon2 - lon1 );
     
var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) + Math.cos(rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(rad(lat2)) * Math.sin(dLong/2) * Math.sin(dLong/2);

var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));   
var d = R * c; 
var end = d.toFixed(3);
```

Comment: Hola, no has dado mucho contexto de tu problema, asi que algunas cosas las voy a asumir. Pero por lo que entiendo quieres obtener el resultado de un punto A a un punto B en unidades de tiempo en vez de distancia. Para ello lo que necesitas si o si es la velocidad con la que se va a mover el objeto que va a trasladarse de dicho punto A a B. Como la velocidad es: `vel = distancia / tiempo` de ahi puedes despejar y obtener: `tiempo = distancia / vel`. Otra cosa a tener en cuenta es que la velocidad generalmente no es constante, asi que podrías obtener una velocidad promedio.

Comment: Aquí encontré un blog (https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-does-google-maps-calculate-travel-time) que habla sobre qué factores tiene en cuenta Google Maps para calcular el tiempo estimado de llegada para una ruta. Quizás te sirva.

Comment: @AndresGardiol Cómo saco la velocidad? es que no logro entender

Comment: No conozco absolutamente nada del contexto en tu aplicación (no has explicado mucho en tu pregunta). Por lo tanto no puedo saber qué variables hay en juego. Sin embargo, como mencioné atrás, la velocidad se calcula: `vel = distancia / tiempo `